# Merge columns of a dataframe by two conditions using aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a matrix like this

```
  P   A   B  C 
  1   2   0  5
  2   1   1  3
  3   0   4  7
  1   1   1  0
  3   1   1  0
  3   0   2  1
  2   3   3  4
```

I want to merge/sort the rows by P and by each of the columns. So that each P value is for each column once and the value for each P in each column is summed up. The result should be:

```
 P  A  B  C
 1  3  0  0 
 1  0  1  0 
 1  0  0  5
 2  4  0  0
 2  0  4  0
 2  0  0  7
 3  1  0  0
 3  0  7  0
 3  0  0  8
```

I tried already `aggregate` but it only helps me to sum up every P value for all columns so that I have just one row for each P.

Comment: because each p row will appear for each column.

Comment: it is something like mixture of merge and split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another idea is to use `diag` function itself to create a matrix. Then you can rbind these matrices together.

```
xx=aggregate(. ~ P, df, sum)
yy=xx[,-1]
yy=as.data.frame(t(yy))
cbind(rep(1:ncol(yy),nrow(yy)),do.call("rbind", lapply(yy, function(xx) diag(xx, nrow = nrow(yy), ncol = nrow(yy)))))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    3    0    0
 [2,]    2    0    1    0
 [3,]    3    0    0    5
 [4,]    1    4    0    0
 [5,]    2    0    4    0
 [6,]    3    0    0    7
 [7,]    1    1    0    0
 [8,]    2    0    7    0
 [9,]    3    0    0    8
```

Comment: You might want to generalize it a bit to account for more columns (i.e. A, B, C, D, E...)

Answer (score 4):

One idea is to split your data frame on `P` and apply a custom function(`fun1`) which creates a matrix with 0 and replaces the diagonal with the sum of the columns. i.e.

```
fun1 <- function(x){
m1 <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(x) - 1, nrow = ncol(x) - 1)
diag(m1) <- sapply(x[-1], sum)
return(m1)
       }

l1 <- split(df, df$P)
do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, fun1))

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    5
# [4,]    4    0    0
# [5,]    0    4    0
# [6,]    0    0    7
# [7,]    1    0    0
# [8,]    0    7    0
# [9,]    0    0    8
```

Or to get it to your desired output, then

```
final_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(rep(names(l1), each = ncol(df)-1), 
                                             do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, fun1))))
names(final_df) <- names(df)

final_df
#  P A B C
#1 1 3 0 0
#2 1 0 1 0
#3 1 0 0 5
#4 2 4 0 0
#5 2 0 4 0
#6 2 0 0 7
#7 3 1 0 0
#8 3 0 7 0
#9 3 0 0 8
```

Comment: hmm there seems to be something wrong with the length of the diagonal

Comment: as long as the matrix is square (which it is 3 x 3 since you have 3 columns;A, B, C) then diagonal shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: ah yes, that's it. In my case it is not diagonal. But for diagonal one's it's working fine! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We get the maximum value of frequency count from 'P' column ('i1'), `aggregate` the columns grouped by 'P' to get the `sum` ('df2'), replicate the rows of 'df2' by the 'i1', `split` the dataset by 'P' and change the non-diagonal elements in other columns to 0 and return it as `data.frame`, `order` and change the row names to NULL.

```
i1 <- max(table(df1$P))
df2 <- aggregate(.~P, df1, sum)
df3 <-  df2[rep(1:nrow(df2), i1)]
res <- unsplit(lapply(split(df3, df3$P), function(x) {
         x[-1] <- diag(3)*x[-1]
         x}), df3$P)
res1 <- res[order(res$P),]
row.names(res1) <- NULL
res1
#  P A B C
#1 1 3 0 0
#2 1 0 1 0
#3 1 0 0 5
#4 2 4 0 0
#5 2 0 4 0
#6 2 0 0 7
#7 3 1 0 0
#8 3 0 7 0
#9 3 0 0 8
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), get the `sum`, grouped by 'P', replicate the rows of the summarised dataset and change the non-diagonal elements to 0 (as discussed in the first solution).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = P
           ][rep(1:.N, i1)
            ][, .SD*diag(ncol(df1)-1), by = P]
#   P A B C
#1: 1 3 0 0
#2: 1 0 1 0
#3: 1 0 0 5
#4: 2 4 0 0
#5: 2 0 4 0
#6: 2 0 0 7
#7: 3 1 0 0
#8: 3 0 7 0
#9: 3 0 0 8
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
d1 <- as.data.frame(diag(i1))
df2 <-  df1 %>% 
             group_by(P) %>% 
             summarise_each(funs(sum)) %>% 
             replicate(i1, ., simplify = FALSE) %>%
             bind_rows() %>% 
             arrange(P)
df2[-1] <- map2(df2[-1], d1, ~.x * .y)
df2
# A tibble: 9 × 4
#      P     A     B     C
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     0     0
#2     1     0     1     0
#3     1     0     0     5
#4     2     4     0     0
#5     2     0     4     0
#6     2     0     0     7
#7     3     1     0     0
#8     3     0     7     0
#9     3     0     0     8
```

Comment: somehow your second solution is the only one that works! Thanks a lot - I was so fixated on using aggregate

Comment: well... sorry, I just found out that with my huge data it is not working. hmm

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the following looks valid too.
Start by computing the sums per "P":

```
s = as.matrix(rowsum(dat[-1], dat$P))
```

Create the final matrix:

```
k = s[rep(1:nrow(s), each = ncol(s)), ]
```

Compute indices to replace with "0"s:

```
k[col(k) != (row(k) - 1) %% ncol(k) + 1] = 0
k
#  A B C
#1 3 0 0
#1 0 1 0
#1 0 0 5
#2 4 0 0
#2 0 4 0
#2 0 0 7
#3 1 0 0
#3 0 7 0
#3 0 0 8
```

data:

```
dat = structure(list(P = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), A = c(2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L), B = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), C = c(5L, 
3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("P", "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Having computed `s`, user20650 's more straightforward alternative:

```
matrix(diag(ncol(s)), nrow(s) * ncol(s), ncol(s), byrow = TRUE) * c(t(s))
```

or, also, messing with other interesting alternatives on the same idea:

```
kronecker(rep_len(1, nrow(s)), diag(ncol(s))) * c(t(s))

diag(ncol(s))[rep(1:ncol(s), nrow(s)), ] * s[rep(1:nrow(s), each = ncol(s)), ]
```

Comment: very nice.( Ive just hardcoded no.'s here), but perhaps a wee but clearer??? `t(matrix(diag(3), nrow=3, ncol=9))  * c(t(s))`

Comment: @user20650 : recycling `diag()` is, indeed, handy here -- didn't think of that. I'll need to take my recycling more seriously...... the parameterization now, I think, seems correct

Comment: nice Alexis, your kronecker method is quite nifty. I think these matrix transforms are the best way to approach this problem...still ...